# How can I save a list of objects to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood the documentation for the MongoDB camel module, but reading the documentation seems to indicate that the incoming body will be transformed into either a document or a list, so it can be inserted into a collection.

Basically, I have a very simple route (TransformRoute) that takes CSV data, transforms it into a java bean, and sends it over an ActiveMQ, marshaled as JSON, using Jackson. The queue is read by another route (PersistRoute) that should just save the data to MongoDB. If I send each java bean as a message over ActiveMQ it works as expected, but if a turn the whole CSV file into a list of java beans and send that over ActiveMQ, it fails and I am honestly a bit stumped.

### TransformRoute

```
@Component
public class TransformRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        DataFormat bind = new BindyCsvDataFormat(UserBean.class);

        from("activemq:unpacked")
            .routeId("transformRoute")
            .unmarshal(bind)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, true)
            .log("${body}")
            .to("activemq:save");
    }
}
```

### PersistRoute

```
@Component
public class PersistRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("activemq:save")
            .routeId("persistRoute")
            .log("Received message at PersistRoute")
            .to("mongodb:connectionBean?database=test&collection=user&operation=save")
            .setBody(simple("${body}"));
    }
}
```

### UserBean

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", isOrdered = true)
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private Integer id;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String firstName;
    @DataField(pos = 3)
    private String surName;
    @DataField(pos = 4)
    private String workEmail;
    @DataField(pos = 5)
    private String personalEmail;
    @DataField(pos = 6)
    private String profession;
}
```

### Error

```
Message History (source location and message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source                                   ID                             Processor                                          Elapsed (ms)
                                         persistRoute/persistRoute      from[activemq://save]                                   3800927
    ...
                                         persistRoute/to4               mongodb:connectionBean?database=test&collection=us            0

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.CamelMongoDbException: Body incorrect type for save
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.lambda$createDoSave$14(MongoDbProducer.java:643) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.lambda$wrap$0(MongoDbProducer.java:260) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.invokeOperation(MongoDbProducer.java:138) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.process(MongoDbProducer.java:125) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:477) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:175) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:132) ~[camel-jms-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:331) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.bson.Document but has type: byte[] on: JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:atlantis-35375-1665732206912-51:1:3:1:1]. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: byte[] to the required type: org.bson.Document with value [B@7f2e6fb due to org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.. Exchange[]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: byte[] to the required type: org.bson.Document with value [B@7f2e6fb due to org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.]
    at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:125) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.lambda$createDoSave$14(MongoDbProducer.java:627) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: byte[] to the required type: org.bson.Document with value [B@7f2e6fb due to org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
    at org.apache.camel.support.SimpleTypeConverter.convertTo(SimpleTypeConverter.java:105) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:479) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:358) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:271) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:123) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:689) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:177) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.converters.MongoDbBasicConverters.fromByteArrayToDocument(MongoDbBasicConverters.java:91) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.converters.MongoDbBasicConvertersLoader.lambda$registerConverters$2(MongoDbBasicConvertersLoader.java:49) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.SimpleTypeConverter.convertTo(SimpleTypeConverter.java:101) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2022-10-14 10:36:38.570  WARN 5841 --- [sConsumer[save]] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: byte[] to the required type: org.bson.Document with value [B@7f2e6fb due to org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.]

org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: byte[] to the required type: org.bson.Document with value [B@7f2e6fb due to org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
    at org.apache.camel.support.SimpleTypeConverter.convertTo(SimpleTypeConverter.java:105) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:479) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:358) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:271) ~[camel-base-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:123) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.lambda$createDoSave$14(MongoDbProducer.java:627) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.lambda$wrap$0(MongoDbProducer.java:260) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.invokeOperation(MongoDbProducer.java:138) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.process(MongoDbProducer.java:125) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:477) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:175) ~[camel-core-processor-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:392) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:132) ~[camel-jms-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:331) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:689) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:177) ~[bson-4.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.converters.MongoDbBasicConverters.fromByteArrayToDocument(MongoDbBasicConverters.java:91) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.converters.MongoDbBasicConvertersLoader.lambda$registerConverters$2(MongoDbBasicConvertersLoader.java:49) ~[camel-mongodb-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.SimpleTypeConverter.convertTo(SimpleTypeConverter.java:101) ~[camel-support-3.19.0.jar:3.19.0]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

### Data logged

```
[ {
  "id" : 100,
  "firstName" : "Alexine",
  "surName" : "McClimans",
  "workEmail" : "Alexine.McClimans@yopmail.com",
  "personalEmail" : "Alexine.McClimans@gmail.com",
  "profession" : "police officer"
}, {
  "id" : 101,
  "firstName" : "Emmey",
  "surName" : "Wildermuth",
  "workEmail" : "Emmey.Wildermuth@yopmail.com",
  "personalEmail" : "Emmey.Wildermuth@gmail.com",
  "profession" : "firefighter"
} ]
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The operation `save` is not meant to be used for a collection of documents, only one document is expected.

The error that you get is related to the fact that it assumes that you try to save only one document but as it could be a JSON or BSON, it first tries to detect whether it is a BSON or a JSON and here it detected (wrongly) a BSON that is why you end up with this strange error.

In your case, you should rather use the [`insert`](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/mongodb-component.html#_insert) operation instead that supports a document, a collection of documents, or an array of documents.

Your route should rather looks like:

```
from("activemq:save")
    .routeId("persistRoute")
    .log("Received message at PersistRoute")
    .to("mongodb:connectionBean?database=test&collection=user&operation=insert")
    .setBody(simple("${body}"));
```

Comment: Have you tested it?